# Visualize .json with 3D program

Tags: json, webgl

I am doing some json loading with webGL, but the thing is that my file is a .json not a .js and the file starts like this :

```
{
  "version" : "0.1.0",

  "comment" : "Generated by MeshLab JSON Exporter",

  "id"      : 1,
  "name"    : "mesh",

  "vertices" :
  [
    {
      "name"       : "position_buffer",
      "size"       : 3,
      "type"       : "float32",
      "normalized" : false,
      "values"     :
      [
        -1.88373, -4.96699, -4.80969, -2.09061, -4.88318, -4.81713,
```

It does not look like the others .js that I have seen. So my thing is that I'd like to visualize it in a program like blender to check if it is a problem from the file.
But I did not find any programs.
And second is this file even supported by the webGL's jsonloader ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't simple json(like this http://learningwebgl.com/lessons/lesson14/Teapot.json) it's  archive with a lot of stuff inside so you need to write your own (or find) parser.
About json loading read this http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=1658

Comment: Thank you JAre, I complete your answer with mine.

Answer (score 1):

The webGL's jsonloader also opens .js which you can make from a .obj with some python's script like the one from Three.js (Thanks to Mr.doob) :

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/utils/exporters/obj/convert_obj_three.py

On the same git there is also loader for .obj.